# VueJS Resource throwing undefined error on exact code as other project

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

I am learning VueJS and I love it! but for the last 2 days I have been stuck on a weird problem.
I made a previous project and there the exact same code DOES work. In my new project (learning project) the identical code does NOT work.

It results in this error:

[image: VueJS error message]

My code is as follow (everything works perfect except the resource):
Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.http.options.root = 'https://myapi.com/v1/list/';
Vue.http.interceptors.push((resource, next) => {
    this.method = 'GET';
    next();
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

Home.vue code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <StatsRowOne></StatsRowOne>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="submit">search</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import StatsRowOne from './elements/StatsRowOne';

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                results: [],
                resource: {}
            }
        },
        components: {
            StatsRowOne: StatsRowOne
        },
        methods: {
            submit() {

                this.resource.get().then(function(response) {
                    alert('done');
                });

            }
        },
        created() {
            this.resource = this.$resource('auto');
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are copying the code correctly? That is because you are using ES6 arrow function syntax, which means the `this.method` on line 7 in `main.js` actually does not point to the `method` setting of the interceptor.

Comment: Ah wait.. you are so right! let me check...

Comment: Seems like you were right... I copied that code (one of the only pieces I didnt take from my other project) from an official Vue page lol... thank you so much, now I know what to look for in the future!

Answer (score 0):

A further explanation from my comment: the `this.method` is undefined on line 7 in your `main.js` file because it is used in an arrow function. Remember that arrow functions in ES6 preserves the lexical `this`, so you are actually not accessing the property correctly because `this` does not point to anything exposed by the interceptor in the callback.

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#request-processing), it appears that you should be using `resource.method` instead.